# Batch - How to return a value from a batch file?

Tags: function, batch-file, return

I know how to return a value from a function in the same batch file, but I've found some problems in returning a value from a different batch file. Here is an example:

File `1.cmd`

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set number=1
call 2.cmd

echo. %number%

ENDLOCAL
exit /B
```

File `2.cmd`

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

ENDLOCAL & set number=2
exit /B
```

And the output is still 1. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 7):

LittleBobbyTables was on the correct track.

Your use of two SETLOCAL but only 1 ENDLOCAL causes the variable to be set, but then the definition is lost because there is an additional implicit ENDLOCAL when the batch exits at EXIT /B. All SETLOCAL are ended whenever a batch or function terminates. Your code simply needs an additional ENDLOCAL before you set the value.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

ENDLOCAL & ENDLOCAL & set number=2
exit /B
```

But it is extremely rare that enableExtensions is needed since extensions are always enabled by default. You should be able to drop SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS and use a single ENDLOCAL.

If for some reason you really do need to enable extensions, then you can use both options on a single SETLOCAL and still need only one ENDLOCAL

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

ENDLOCAL & set number=2
exit /b
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a hard time explaining it properly, but the combination of both

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

in your `2.cmd` file are causing a delay in the evaluation of the variable.

If either is individually enabled, `%number%` should still be set to 2, but together, `%number%` will be set to 1.

Comment: Thanks, without SETLOCAL and ENDLOCAL at 2.cmd code it works :)